# How to solve differential equations for linear operators?

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, operator-theory

I want to solve the differential equation

$$ BA = \frac{\partial}{\partial t} A $$

for $A$. Here $A : H_1 \mapsto H_2$ and $B : H_2 \mapsto H_2$ are operators and $H_1, H_2$ are some Hilbert spaces. $A$ is directly dependent on $t$. Derivative of operator wrt. parameter is defined as

$$\frac{d}{dt} A(t) = \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \frac{A(t+\epsilon) - A(t)}{\epsilon}$$

Exponent of an operator is defined by the MacLaurin series:

$$ e^B = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n!} B^n$$

If $B$ doesn't depend on $t$ directly $(\frac{\partial B}{\partial t} = 0)$ then it is easy to verify that

$$ A_0 = e^{Bt} $$

is a solution. Also

$$ A = c \cdot e^{Bt} $$

is a solution for any scalar $c$.

**Questions**: Are those the only solutions? Why? What about the case when $\frac{\partial B}{\partial t} \neq 0$?

References are welcome.

Comment: You should try to treat the case when $\dim(H_1) = \dim(H_2) = 1$ and then see how you can generalise, and then check if what you conjectured works!